# VS 2022 ASP.NET Core 7 MVC and MS Access

Tags: ms-access, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-7.0

I am writing a demo ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app that will connect to a MS Access database. In `appsettings.json` it defaults to SQL Server LocalDb database:

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Test1Context": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test1Context-5b1740e8-aa81-481d-9225-5d1ee5426738;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

In the Server Explore, I can see the MS Access Database. When I attempt to add the MS Access database in "Connected Services", there is no entry. So how do I connect to the MS Access database?

I tried to use "Connected Services" to connect to the MS Access database.

Answer (score 0):

You could reference this sample.
Access DB
[image]
Read

```
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void test()
        {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM acdb1;";
            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query);
            var ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=E:\\temp\\Database11.accdb; ";
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.Write(reader.GetString(0)+" ");                        
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(1));
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```

Console output
[image]

Or use `"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=E:\\temp\\Database11.accdb;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;"`when need password.